# Out Put Random Numbers to TextBox

Tags: c#, random, collections, textbox

I am new to C#. I have created a random class that manages to generate some not so very random numbers. But my problem is that I want to output these numbers to 6 different text boxes. I'm sure sure there is a more efficient way of doing it which is also less long winded.
and this is how I have done it:

```
protected void genBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Random RandomClass = new Random();
    int num1 , num2, num3 , num4, num5 , num6;
    num1 = RandomClass.Next(1,49);
    num2 = RandomClass.Next(1,49);
    num3 = RandomClass.Next(1,49);
    num4 = RandomClass.Next(1,49);
    num5 = RandomClass.Next(1,49);
    num6 = RandomClass.Next(1,49);



    TextBox1.Text = num1.ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = num2.ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = num3.ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = num4.ToString();
    TextBox5.Text = num5.ToString();
    TextBox6.Text = num6.ToString();
```

Comment: what is the problem/question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an array, then loop?

```
Random RandomClass = new Random();
Control[] textboxes = new Contro[] {TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3,TextBox4,TextBox5,TextBox6};
foreach(Control c in textboxes) 
     c.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
```

Or a `List<TextBox>` then `ForEach` ?

```
List<TextBox> textboxes = new List<TextBox>() {TextBox1,TextBox2,TextBox3,TextBox4,TextBox5,TextBox6};
textboxes.ForEach(x => x.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString());
```

Comment: are you the same steve from minecraft? :P

Comment: @JohnOdom nope I could ask my son if he knows you :-)

Comment: Thanks Steve, this is nice and short but Text in 'code' c.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString() is causing me errors. i thought its the same as in textbox.text, but the error massage  says i should not be use as a type. do i need to declare this somewhere before this line?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Did you fix it?

Comment: yes thank you. now iam trying color the textboxes by a range of numbers e.g if the the number generated < 10 give it this color. if its btwn 10 and 20 give this color etc. i tried to do it with  textboxes.Background = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

Comment: Post a new question, you will get more attention to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works, but you don't need all those extra variables.

```
protected void genBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random RandomClass = new Random();
    TextBox1.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
    TextBox2.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
    TextBox3.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
    TextBox4.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
    TextBox5.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
    TextBox6.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
protected void genBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Random RandomClass = new Random();

        TextBox1.Text = RandomClass.Next(1, 49).ToString();
        TextBox2.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
        TextBox3.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
        TextBox4.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
        TextBox5.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
        TextBox6.Text = RandomClass.Next(1,49).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have your text boxes on different panel controls and you may have more text boxes. Do this:

```
// Name your random num text boxes with some convention, like txtRand1. But not the others
// Recursive func to read all text boxes
private void RecFillRandTextBoxes(Control parent, rand)
{
    foreach (Control  c in parentcontrols) 
    {
        if (typeof(c) is TextBox && c.Name.StartsWith("txtRand"))
            c.Text = Next(1,49).ToString();
        else
            RecFillRandTextBoxes(c, rand);          
    }
}
```

Then just call it in your form class on `genBtn_Click`

```
RecFillRandTextBoxes(this, rand);
```

Comment: This did not answer the question, and the default constructor of Random is already using a time dependent seed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GvS Yes, with seed I overworked the question. Other than that my answer gives nice idea how to have any number of text boxes on the form, which need to be populated with random number. Not just fixed number of text boxes on fixed number of surfaces